# CSS Website Help Please

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website for a friend. I am new to CSS. When I open the code in the browser the webpage is not as wide as the screen. I would like it to fit the screen and not be so small. I currently use the free Coffee Cup HTML editor which is just a basic editor with preview capabilities.  I've been researching sites like W3Schools, HTML Dog.  Can anyone suggest some good resources?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">                                       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

 <title>ABA Coach</title>


     <style type="text/css" media="screen">




     body       { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      body    { color: #333; font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; }
      h2    { color: #333; }
      a    { color: #337810; }
      p    { margin: 0 0 18px; }
      #container  { width: 760px; margin: 0 auto;}
      #wrapper  { float: left; width: 100%; }



      /* Header */
      #header   { background-color: lightsteelblue; background-image: url('head.jpg'); border-style:ridge; border-bottom: 5px solid ; }
      /*
      #header h1   { color: black; margin: 0 0 3px; padding: 30px 18px 0; }
      #header p  { color: black; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 18px; }*/


      /* Content Style */
      #navigation  { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
      #navigation ul { padding: 0 18px 9px; }
      #extra   { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
      #extra small { font-size: 11px; line-height: 18px; }
      #content  { }
      #content p, #extra p { padding-right: 18px; }

      /* Content Positioning & Size */
      #navigation  { float: left; margin-left: -742px; width: 175px; }
      #content  { margin: 0 215px 36px 215px; }
      #extra   { float: left; margin-left: -200px; width: 175px; }  

      /* Footer */
      #footer   { background: grey; border-bottom: 2px solid #999; clear: left; width: 100%; }
      #footer a  { color: #eee; }
      #footer p  { color: #ccc; margin: 0; padding: 0 18px 10px; }
      #footer ul  { border-bottom: 1px solid #555; list-style: none; margin: 0 18px 6px; padding: 10px 0 6px; }
      #footer li  { display: inline; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; padding-right: 5px; }


    .center {
    text-align: center; }


    </style>


        </head>
        <body>

      <div id="container">

        <div id="header"> 

        <div class="center">
        <p><a href="index.html"><img  src="images/head.jpg"  alt="logo" width="100%" height="10%"/></a></p> 



      </div>

      <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="content">

        <h2>All About ABA Coach</h2>

        <p>ABA Coach is a company dedicated to working with individuals and families to provide training and behavior coaching. We have over twenty years of experience working of all levels of abilities. Our experience ranges from (ECI), public and private schools including college level work, independent corporations, and churches.</p>
        <p>ABA Coach  provides expert level functional behavior assessments, behavior intervention plans, IEP development and ARD process intervention, classroom consultations, and behavior intervention plans.</p>
        <p>ABA Coach administers presentations,consultations, hands on workshops, training for teachers, paraprofessionals, other professionals such as therapists, and siblings and family members.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="navigation">
       <h2>Links</h2>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="client.html">Client Log-in</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="forms.html">Online Forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="references.html">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact ABA Coach</a></li>
       </ul>
        <img src="images/beach.jpg" width="130" height="105" alt="" title="" border="0" align="" />   

      </div>

      <div id="extra">
       <h2>What We Can Accomplish</h2>

       <p>We can provide concrete data of the results of our work.</p>


       <p><small>Reports and data included:</small></p>

       <p><small><li>Detailed data and charts of specific goals and changes.</li></small></p>
       <p><small><li>Video evidence of changes.</li></small></p>
       <p><small><li> specific goals.</li></small></p>

      </div>
      <div id="footer">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="client.html">Client Log-in</a></li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="forms.html">Online Forms</a></li>
        <li><a href="references.html">References</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact ABA Coach</a></li>
       </ul>
       <p> Copyright 2011 :  : 




      </div>
     </div>
     <p><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></p>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would recommend webmonkey's tutorials for learning HTML and CSS:

[http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorials/]

This site got me started making basic web pages with plain HTML, before I learned web- and server-programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best book on CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css)

Comment: more 'good resources': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084/can-you-recommend-a-good-css-online-resource-or-book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect this line:

```
#container  { width: 760px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

To do?

Comment: I guess I was thinking it was holding the header in place... the banner.

Comment: It's not. It's setting the width of the container div (Which in your code contains the ENTIRE page) and giving it a fixed width of 760 pixels. If you want a fluid width page remove that line.

Comment: I tried that and the left column "Links" squishes to the middle of the page and over runs the middle column.

Comment: I changed the container to 960 and the #navigation to -942. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

A statement such as `width: 100%` would expand that element to the entire width of the parent element. Doing this with the `body` tag, I suppose, will expand the body to fit the entire screen.